# MSVC: explicit template instantiation fails while implicit instantiation succeeds

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I just came across a problem with MSVC (Version 12 Update 5):

Explicitly instantiating a template function fails, if that function has an overload which is disabled through SFINAE. However, calling that function (thereby implicity instantiating it) works.

Sample code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t< std::is_integral<T>::value,  // test is true for T=int
void> foo( T& ) {}

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t< std::is_pointer<T>::value,  // test is false for T=int
void> foo( T& ) {}

void bar( )
{
  int i;
  foo( i );  // calls foo( int& ) (obviously), compiles fine
}
template void foo( int& );  // explicit instantiation, throws compiler error
```

The compiler error I get is `error C2794: 'type' : is not a member of any direct or indirect base class of 'std::enable_if<false,void>'`.
The same code seems to be fine with GCC (apart from missing the main function): [live on Ideone](http://ideone.com/K6ro4u).

Is this an MSVC bug? Is there a good way to make these explicit template instantiations?

Comment: As both gcc/clang accept it, I would say it is a MSVC bug. (I don't think it is ill formed without diagnostic required).

Comment: Compiles online at http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net. And at http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual

Comment: MSVC12 does not support C++14 well (or at all).

Comment: What is the line `template void foo( int& );` supposed to accomplish? Are you declaring the function after it's been defined?

Comment: @Jonathan: that line is supposed to instantiate the template function with template parameters deduced from the arguments given (int&), without actually calling it. Look for "explicit template function instantiation" if you want to know more.

Comment: @RaoulSteffen So, we're saying like force that version of the template to compile? Why would we want to do that?

Comment: @JonathanMee e.g. we want to have this instantiation in a binary library so that other code can call it without instantiating it.

Comment: @Jonathan: What n.m. said, or simply to make sure it will compile when I use that library function weeks (or months) later.

Comment: @n.m. Out of curiosity, is there a C++14 SFINAE change at play here ?

Comment: @Quentin dunno, looks like `std::enable_if_t` being a C++14 thing is just not supported,

Comment: @n.m.: It is not `std::enable_if_t`. The exact same thing happens when I use `std::enable_if<...>::type`, which is C++11. And I don't think the issue is with `std::enable_if`, but with the compiler working out the SFINAE. It just happens to manifest when you use it like I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following allows to instantiate the function, making sure it compiles and should (by my understanding) also put it into the .obj-file:

```
namespace {
  template <typename T>
  void helper( T& A )
  {
    foo( A );
  }

  template void helper( int& );
}
```

The trick here is, that `helper(..)` is neither overloadad, nor disabled for any type. Sorting out the disabled overloads is delayed to the 'call' to `foo(..)` within `helper(..)`, which MSVC succeeds to resolve.

EDIT:
As we have seen that other compilers understand my original code, as well as newer versions of MSVC (thanks Niall), I assume it is a bug of my version of MSVC, and consider that part question sufficiently thought over.