# MSVC compilation failure on explicit variadic template function instantiation

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sfinae, forward-declaration, internal-compiler-error

I've distilled my problem to a small example, pardon the macros. It seems a similar problem from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38952448/msvc-explicit-template-instantiation-fails-while-implicit-instantiation-succeed) post is no longer an issue in VS and compiles fine. I believe I have a more specialized version of this problem that hasn't been fixed but want to make sure I'm not missing something. The following code compiles in GCC and runs expectedly, but gives error C2893 (Failed to specialize function template) in VS:

Macros.h:

```cpp
#define If(x) \
  template<class T,class...Args, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, x>::value>::type* = nullptr>
#define Do void Func(Args... args)
```

Definition.cpp:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Macros.h"
using namespace std;


int answer  = 42;
double pie  = 3.14;
string s    = "Hello World";

// Function Definitions
If(int)    Do { cout << answer << endl; }
If(double) Do { cout << pie << endl; }
If(string) Do { cout << s << endl; }

// Explicit Instantiations
template void Func<int>(int, double, string);
template void Func<double>();
template void Func<string>();
```

Usage.cpp:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include "Macros.h"

// Template Function Declaration
If(T) Do;

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    Func<int>(5, 2.0, string("hello"));
    Func<double>();
    Func<string>();
}
```

As with the example in the other post it works correctly if the instantiations come from actual use in a function. Doing so is simple with this example but not so simple with my code.

Comment: Where are the macros defined?  How is that included into your source code?  What is the full error message you get from the compiler?

Comment: The macros are defined right there where it says macros... I'm not using them in source code just for brevity in the length of the distilled example. The error message is exactly what is posted in the question: C2893 (Failed to specialize function template)

Comment: Are the macros defined in a header?  How are the macro definitions included into the source of the two .cpp files you've included?  I'm looking for a [mre].

Comment: Apologies, I thought it was obvious they would just be pasted in each cpp before use or included from a header, either way makes no difference. I'll edit it to have the include once I get the chance